# Is it safe to eat uncooked (raw) oats

Tags: nutrition, malnutrition

I eat 150 grams of raw oats every morning together with other things, and I have just heard that oats should always be cooked (boiled). (I do a lot of exercise)

I heard that in the long run, raw oats can cause  problems such as irritable colon, gasses, digestive problems and inflammation and deficiencies in magnesium, iron, calcium and potasium due to the phytic acid present in oats.

I have also heard that it takes a long time to digest, and it can leave remains in the intestines.

The thing is that appart from occasional gasses I do not feel bad and my blood analysis always are corect.

Comment: Humans learned to cook food 10s of thousands of years ago. It has many benefits that you might want to look into, one of which is making oats taste much better.

Comment: Most people who eat "raw oats" soak them in some liquid, which "softens" them up.  If you eat them completely raw, then there is a possible risk of irritating the gut.  That irritation can cause inflammation, which is what would lead to poor absorption of Mg++, Fe, Ca++, and K+.  If the way you are eating the oats is not causing irritation, then there would be no issue with absorption.  In other words, if you are feeling well doing what you're doing, then you're probably fine.